# Outlook Calendar with Powershell NOT pulling up all items

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have a powershell script to pull calendar invites from my default outlook folder. While i execute the code, it only pulls partial information(no error messages) AKA if there are 10 meetings on my calendar, only 4 shows up. Did anyone encounter similar issue and what can i do to fix it?

```
 Function Get-OutlookCalendar {
     Add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null
     $olFolders = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders” -as [type]
     $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
     $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
     $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderCalendar)
     $folder.items |
     Select-Object -Property start,RequiredAttendees, Subject, IsRecurring, Organizer,ConversationID,RecurrenceState,OptionalAttendees,Body

} 
$start_date=(Get-date).AddDays(-2) |Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy'
$end_date=Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy'
Get-OutlookCalendar| where-object { $_.start -gt [datetime]$start_date -and $_.start -le [datetime]$end_date } | sort-object start
```

Comment: How is a start date of `two days ago or newer, but not newer than today` relevant for this anyway? And are all of those 10 meetings within that range? Also, `$start_date=(Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Date` would eliminate the need for the [datetime] in `-gt [datetime]$start_date` - unnecessary conversion back and forth between `[System.String]` and `[System.DateTime]`.

Comment: Hey User, Good news - I've figure out part of the issue. I dissected your script and ran it against my own calendar. While I agree with notjustme that you have some superfluous code in there, that isn't the issue. In my case, the issue is that it doesn't show recurring appointments. I haven't found a way around this yet (hence this isn't an answer), but the issue appears to be specifically that recurring appointments aren't showing up. Can you confirm if it is the same for you?

Comment: Most likely the recurring entries started earlier than 2 days ago. Whey they were created is their start.

Comment: @V3rmouth - Thank you for the response. For me, there is no pattern, meetings i see few meetings where i am part of DL, my email is in TO and few recurring meetings also showup.

Comment: @notjustme - Agree with you on the excessive conversions. I tried the code you recommended initially and since i wasn't getting expected result, thought of doing the conversion to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Doug - When the meeting invite was sent shouldnt matter, right? as long as the start time falls in between those dates. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Let me check again.

Comment: Voting to close this, as @user1550159 asked a very similar question 5 days later and that question has what appears to be a valid answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819837/how-to-get-outlook-recurring-meeting-items-in-powershell