# How to get outlook recurring meeting items in powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am using below script to pull outlook calendar items and it works for events that occur once. It fails for recurring meeting invites as the start date on it would be when the invite was sent and not the occurrence start time. Also, i dont see any variable referencing the occurrence end date, so cant dynamically lookup for the occurrence. Any suggestions on how to get that?

```
Function Get-OutlookCalendar {
     Add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null
     $olFolders = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders” -as [type]
     $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
     $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
     $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderCalendar)
     $folder.items |
     Select-Object -Property start,RequiredAttendees, Subject, IsRecurring, Organizer,ConversationID,RecurrenceState,OptionalAttendees,Body
} 
$start_date=(Get-date).AddDays(-2) |Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy'
$end_date=Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy'
Get-OutlookCalendar| where-object { $_.start -gt [datetime]$start_date -and $_.start -le [datetime]$end_date } | sort-object start
```

Comment: So I was right? I haven’t had a chance to check again.

Comment: Yes Doug, the code is looking for first start date instead of recurrence start date. Any recommendations on how to sole that issue?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll let you know.

Comment: For future readers, see this answer for an example of retrieving recurring appointments in addition to non-recurring appointments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527430/olfoldercalendar-in-outlook-interop-assembly-not-showing-all-calendar-entries#answer-64269075

Answer (score 1):

You can try below switch:

```
switch ($item.IsRecurring)
{
    $false {
        if ($item.start -ge $dt -and $item.start -lt ($dt).AddDays(1))
        {
            $item | Select-Object -Property Subject, Start, Duration, Location, RequiredAttendees
        }
    }

    $true {
        try {
            $rec=$item.GetRecurrencePattern()
            $recitem=$rec.GetOccurrence($dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + $item.Start.ToString("HH:mm"))
            $recitem | Select-Object -Property Subject, Start, Duration, Location, RequiredAttendees, IsRecurring
        }
        catch {}
        finally {}

    }
}
```